# How do I get current response length in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, response, content-length, cakephp-2.5

I'm using: CakePHP 2.5.6
Trying to read the length of the response like this:

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

Class AppController extends Controller {

    public function afterFilter() {
        parent::afterFilter();
        pr($this->response->length());
    }

}
```

To no avail though, the value returned is empty.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `$this->response->length();`

Edit:
Or read the set headers with `$this->response->header();`

In both cases the value you will get will probably not be accurate, because the webserver can change the content/headers and will adjust the size.

Comment: I see I made a typo. Your suggestion is actually what I tried.